# Uncaught ReferenceError PrimeFaces is not defined in my Google Console

Tags: jquery, maven, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I know there are several stack-topics which are exact same of mine, but didn't get how to solve that issue in my Chrome console.

Please note that currently things are displayed correctly, it's just I would solve anything in my project.

Pressing F12 i got this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined

This is my page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 
<h:head>  
    <h1 class="title ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"><p:spacer width="100" height="10" />PrimeFaces Test</h1>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">PrimeFaces Test</ui:insert></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head> 
<h:body>  
    <h:form> 
    <h:selectOneMenu binding="#{bindingTestClass.menu}" />
    <h:panelGroup binding="#{bindingTestClass.panelGroup}"/>
    </h:form> 
</h:body> 
</html>
```

That's my Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.itcuties.examples.simplejsf</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-jsf2-with-primefaces</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>simple-jsf2</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF 2 API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Themes All-in-One! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>primefaces-repository</id>
            <name>Primefaces repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>jsf2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I add that the network of Google Developer Tools doesn't show anything of suspect.

Bindings works just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a `h1` tag with `p:spacer` in `h:head` that might be the issue.

Comment: Everytime an user binds a component to backing bean in an attempt to populate the component tree using overly verbose and barely readable Java mess instead of clean and self-documenting XHTML+XML code, a kitten dies. Please stop it.

Comment: it turns out that it appears only if i put the binding approach in the body. Really strange uh!?